# Centre two inline block elements vertically

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.logo h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0066CC;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.logo h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #C61476;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <h1>MyLogo</h1>
  <h2>My Catchy Slogan</h2>
</div>
<!-- .logo -->
```

That gives me this:

[image: logo]

Can someone please tell me how I can get the slogan bit to align to the centre of the MyLogo text no matter what height the `<div class="logo">` changes to?

I've tried many solutions found through Google, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given both of the elements are set to `display: inline-block;` and are therefore classed as `inline` you can use `vertical-align: middle;` to center them vertically.

> **vertical-align**
>   The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

*vertical-align (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)*

```css
.logo h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0066CC;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #C61476;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <h1>MyLogo</h1>
  <h2>My Catchy Slogan</h2>
</div>
<!-- .logo -->
```

Comment: Why must I set both as `vertical-align: middle;`? I tried this with the `.logo h2` only but it didn't work! Yours works however!

Comment: By default `vertical-align` is set to `baseline`. Not applying `vertical-align: middle;` to `.logo h1` means that the `baseline` is in line with the bottom of the **M**, **L** and **o**s on **MyLogo**. As **My Catchy Slogan** is vertically aligned in relation to the `baseline` (see the mozilla docs for more info) it appears in perceivably wrong location. Setting `vertical-align: middle;` on `.logo h1` moves the `baseline` itself towards the middle of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/osn7dnvc/)

```
.logo h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        color: #0066CC;
        margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .logo h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        color: #C61476;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .logo{
        display: table;
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="logo">
    <h1>MyLogo</h1>
    <h2>My Catchy Slogan</h2>
</div><!-- .logo -->
```